# Android: open images from webview in full screen mode

Tags: android

I have some images displayed inside WebView and this webview displayed inside GridView, and i want to display each image in full screen mode (new activity) after on image click, is that possible?
And if it's possible where i should use onclick event ? Webview.onclick or gridview.onitemclick... ?

this is where i display image in webview

```
        WebView webview=(WebView)myView.findViewById(R.id.wv_tool_image);
        webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        String html = "<html><body>" + "<img src=\"" + SaveSettings.ServerURL +"Images/"+ imagepath+ "\" width=\"100%\" /></body></html>";
        webview.setInitialScale(30);
        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullscreen is composed by 2 parts:

1. Remove the menu
2. Make Activity immersive

For removing the menu there are 2 ways to do it:

a) In the styles.xml create a Style for an Activity without menu and then pass the style in the AndroidManifest to the registered Activity:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And the in the manifest

```
<activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" ... />
```

b) In the Activity do it programatically `getSupportActionbar().hide()`

To set the Activity immersive you always have to find the *rootest* view and then set some properties, in this case it could be your WebView:

```
    yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

When an immersive Activity is used by the first time for the user, the OS will take care of displaying instructions for exiting it.

Additionally an alternative way to do what you are looking for is using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: thanks @cutiko , but how can i pass the url of each image clicked to the fullscreen activity and display it in ImageView or other webview ?

Comment: Ho! Add it to your Intent using putExtra("YOUR_KEY", theUrl); and then get it in the other Activity with getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_KEY");

Comment: and how to put that url or display it in imageView? @cutiko

Comment: Your question mislead me, I thougth the only problem was the fullscreen. Then I would recommend, use my fullscreen suggedtion, forget about the WebView and use Picasso. The link is added on the last edit.